# How to structure this constraint satisfaction problem?

Tags: algorithm, compression, constraints, constraint-programming, lossless-compression

This is a continuation of my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278359/figuring-out-the-underlying-construction-of-a-final-set

To re-post the question in a more CS sort of way, how would you find `A` if only given `B`?

```
$ A = [ 1, 5, 10 ]
$ B = f(A)
$ B == [ 1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 15, 16 ]
(true)
$ B == { 1, 5, 10, 5+1, 10+1, 10+5, 10+5+1 }
(true)
$ solve(B)
[ 1, 5, 10 ]
```

`f()` finds the set of unique values from all nonempty combinations.

Since `A` is always a subset of `B`, I assume there could be a brute-force method where you try each combination of elements in `B` (that’s not *all* elements of `B`,) until you solve for the entire set. But, this would be extremely inefficient. (I'm imagining something like order N factorial...) Since there are multiple solutions, you’d either need to compute the entire set, or stop after a certain threshold.

After some discussion in the comments, I believe this is a constraint satisfaction problem. How would this be structured? (Pseudocode is fine.)

For mega bonus points: how could this be solved for if we assume that A is *not* a subset of B?

For example:

```
$ B = [15, 16, 15.5, .5, 10.5]
$ solve(B)
[.5, 1, 5, 10]
```

Another way to frame this question: What would a lossless compression algorithm that finds the smallest set of base values look like? (The mapping between base values and output data can be ignored.)

Comment: [Constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) solver might work. Don't ask me how to write it.

Comment: @GuyCoder Amazing! I think that may actually be the answer here. Found this library which may do the trick: https://labix.org/python-constraint

Comment: Many modern programming languages either embed a constraint solver or have access to one via a library. While I am aware of them and know how they work, the problems I typically work on don't need one. If that Python solver doesn't work there are others such as [ECLiPSe](https://eclipseclp.org/) or [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) solvers such as Microsoft [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3)

Comment: Use set union, which eliminates duplicates in sets.

Comment: In your last example B does not contain all possible summings like 1 + 0.5 = 1.5 and 1 + 0.5 + 10 = 11.5. is that expected / your desired result?

Comment: @sascha correct! The goal here is not to generate B, but to figure out A. (Or, the best possible option for A.) I simplified the initial question, but ideally we can solve for any B, whether or not it is a complete set of combinations of A.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of element in A is n , then number of element of B would be (2^n) -1.
That means number of  element in B is equal to the number of all possible subset of A .

For Example

if A={a,b,c}
 then B={a,b,c,a+b,a+c,b+c,a+b+c}

To get all the elements of B, we can iterate from 1 to (2^n)-1.
 Now from each number we will calculate different element of B.

> Let
>          A={a,b,c}.
>          n=3,Number of element in A
>
> ```
>    For each i from 1 to 2^n-1, we will check each bit(j) of i from 0 to n-1.
>    if jth bit is 1, we will take jth element of A for finding ith element of B.
>    Such way we will add some number from A for finding ith element such that
>    their index's bit in i is 1.
> ```

For example,

```
1   001     B[0]=a
2   010     B[1]=b
3   011     B[2]=a+b
4   100     B[3]=c
5   101     B[4]=a+c
6   110     B[5]=b+c
7   111     B[6]=a+b+c
```

So total complexity will be n*2^n.

Pseudo code:

```
b=[]
for i in (from 1 to 2^n-1):
   ith=0
   for j in(from 0 to n-1)
       if(jth bit in i is 1)
           ith+=A[j]
   #inner_loop_end
   b.append(ith)
```

Comment: Very interesting to use bitwise logic to figure out B! Unfortunately, I think this requires that we already know the values of A, and calculate B, which is the opposite direction of what I’m looking for. If you didn’t know A, would there be a way to figure it out from B?

Comment: I would love your solution to this problem :--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941975/how-do-i-solve-this-variation-of-josephus-problem